# How to count words in a dataframe?

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-science-model, jupyter, descriptive-statistics

I would like to count how many Male and female who answer (ex. Biking / Cycling).

Below is the sample data:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [Series.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) method will return `True` for str elements in a series that contain a substring. So `df[df.OABP.str.contains('Biking / Cycling')].groupby('Gender').size()` should give you the answer.